# How to dynamically route to any page in SwiftUI, I need to jump from the universal link to the corresponding page

Tags: routes, react-router, swiftui, uikit

SwiftUI does not have React's routing registry, nor does the UIKit framework JLRoute registry, can not match the link to jump to the corresponding page, is there any good solution recommended?